# How to change between sprite action animations seamlessly without running into OOM?

Tags: android, animation, out-of-memory, animationdrawable

I have sprite animations such as run, sleep, walk, jump, ect. Each of these animations work by themselves, but I run into memory issues when I attempt to change animations with setBackgroundResource() to a different set of animationa while the previous animation is active. I believe the previous animation set is not being cleared from memory. What can be done to avoid memory issues?

Memory error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.debug, PID: 5668
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5644812 byte allocation with 1290256 free bytes and 1260KB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2228)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4215)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3939)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimationDrawable.java:324)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:294)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:2549)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:2320)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4210)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:18537)
```

I have different animation files in my Drawable folder. Here is my running xml setup.

anim_sprite_run.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0001" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0002" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0003" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0004" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0005" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0006" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0007" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0008" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0009" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0010" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0011" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0012" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0013" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0014" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0015" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0016" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0017" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0018" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0019" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0020" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0021" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0022" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0023" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0024" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/run0025" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

In code, I start the running animation like this

```
ivSprite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_sprite_run);
            ivSprite.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) ivSprite.getBackground();
                    mAnimationDrawable.start();
                }
            });
```

After 10 seconds, I call another snippet of code that references the sleep animation. This is where it crashes due to OOM

```
ivSprite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_sprite_sleep);
            ivSprite.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) ivSprite.getBackground();
                    mAnimationDrawable.start();
                }
            });
```

Before calling the sleep animation I have tried the following:

```
ivSprite.setBackgroundResource(0);
ivSprite.clearAnimation();
mAnimationDrawable.stop();
```

I try to set the background to null, to clear the previous animations. And then I call clearAnimation() for extra assurance. And finally I stop the previous animation. None of this prevents the OOM error, and I am out of ideas.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution! It is a culmination of everything that I have been attempting.

However, moving the animations to drawable-nodpi seems to be the key to prevent the OOM error. Android may be assuming resources as /drawable-mdpi as default.

Additionally, I added a couple more lines of code to help with managing memory. I null my mAnimationDrawable object, and I also invoke garbage collector. Hopefully these solutions help others working with sprite animations. Cheers!

```
ivSprite.setBackgroundResource(0);
ivSprite.clearAnimation();
mAnimationDrawable.stop();
mAnimationDrawable = null;
// invoke garbage collector
System.gc();
```